Chrome does not return IdentityServer authentication cookie
I am debugging a problem with a legacy ASPNETCore authentication system that uses IdentityServer4. It seems to be a problem with how Chrome (and Edge) handles a cookie.
When the Login page posts (via HTTPS) the user's credentials, the Login endpoint responds with a 302 redirect to a callback URL on the same server (/connect/authorize/callback). This response contains 3 new cookies:

.AspNetCore.Identity.Application : path=/; secure; samesite=lax; httponly
idsrv.session : path=/; secure; samesite=none
idsrv :  expires= Tue, 30 Apr 2024 14:29:35 GMT; path=/; secure; samesite=none; httponly

With Firefox, the browser then sends a request to the callback URL. That request includes all 3 of these cookies, and everything works.
But with Chrome or Edge, the request to the callback URL includes the first two cookies does not include the idsrv cookie, so that request fails and my users are sent back to the Login page.
Why wouldn't Chrome include a cookie that it has just received?
Chrome tell me (via the Network tab) that the idsrv cookie is present in the HTTPS post response, that it is not filtered out, an it has these properties:

Expires / Max-Age = (15 minutes in the future)
Size = 902
HttpOnly = true
Secure = true
SameSite = none


But the cookie is not visible on the Application tab, suggesting it is not being stored, correct?

I have tried setting SameSite=Lax on the idsrv cookie, and extending the expiry time, but that has no effect.

Are you using HTTP or HTTPS?
If you ar using HTTP in the browser, then cookies will be lost. I did blog about how to troubleshoot this at https://nestenius.se/2023/10/09/debugging-cookie-problems/
Today you must always use HTTPS with OpenID-Connect.

HTTPS. Two of the cookies are stored by the browser but one is being ignored/lost. I have updated the question to highlight that fact.

Yes, the browsers can reject cookies as well, so as I mentioned in my blog post, this is often due to samesite not being correct (strict instead of lax) or not using HTTPS. Are you using HTTPS? And yes, different browsers can behave slightly differently.

Yes, I'm using HTTPS.
Your blogpost is very useful, but it does not cover the scenario that I am seeing: there is no error message on the Network tab to indicate that the cookie is being rejected by the browser, and yet that cookie is not displayed in the Application tab.

when you look at the cookies under the application tab, you are only seeing the cookies associated with that domain usprep.... You need to choose or visit the domain for your identityserver to see the cookies fo it.
